# Google chrome console not printing code after redirecting to a different webpage

Tags: javascript

So I am using the console in google chrome on a website and I have my code to redirect me to a different page later in the code but it is on that same website and all of the code after that line stops when that other page in the same website has loaded an help to fix?

```
javascript: (function() {
  function find_product(element, nameofprod) {
    let arr = document.getElementsByTagName(element);
    let indextoclick = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let s = arr[i].innerHTML;
      if (s.includes(nameofprod)) {
        arr[i].click();
      }
    }
  }
  let product_keyword = 'Supreme®/Hanes® Boxer Briefs (4 Pack)';
  find_product('a', product_keyword);
})();

javascript: setTimeout(function() {
  function auto_complete_byTagName(tagname, val) {
    let arr = document.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].innerHTML == val) {
        arr[i].selected = true;
      }
    }
  }
  auto_complete_byTagName('option', 'Large');
  setTimeout(function(){},1000);
  document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].click();

},1000);

setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout";
}, 2300);
```

After the function above the rest of the code just doesn't run at all any reason why or a way to fix? Thanks

Comment: A new page wipes out whatever was happening previously. You can use cookies if you need to maintain state or pass values to a next page, but the JavaScript on the next page will have to read those cookies to use them.

Comment: So I have the cookie created but how would I call or return it after 
   setTimeout(function() {
     window.location.href = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout";
   }, 2300);

Comment: Read the value of the cookie on the new page.